# WIA Document Handling Status returns 0 even though the ADF has pages loaded

Tags: vba, wia, image-scanner

I'm trying to scan from an ADF using VBA and the Windows Image Acquisition library (WIA).  I am trying to check to see if there are pages loaded in the ADF so I know whether to scan another page.  This function seems to work well in Windows 7 (my dev machine) but not in Windows XP (the production machines).  I know MS made some changes to WIA when it released Vista, so this may be the root of the issue.

I'll include the entire function call to hopefully provide enough context to my question.  This function is part of a class module I've written, so it references other functions within the class module.  In the interest of brevity, I've left those other functions out, but will gladly post them if requested.

```
'Windows Imaging Acquisition (WIA) Constants
Private Const wiaFormatBMP As String = "{B96B3CAB-0728-11D3-9D7B-0000F81EF32E}"
Private Const wiaFormatGIF As String = "{B96B3CB0-0728-11D3-9D7B-0000F81EF32E}"
Private Const wiaFormatJPEG As String = "{B96B3CAE-0728-11D3-9D7B-0000F81EF32E}"
Private Const wiaFormatPNG As String = "{B96B3CAF-0728-11D3-9D7B-0000F81EF32E}"
Private Const wiaFormatTIFF As String = "{B96B3CB1-0728-11D3-9D7B-0000F81EF32E}"

Public Function ScanPage(Optional ShowScanningWizard As Boolean = True, _
                         Optional OverWrite As Boolean = False, _
                         Optional AppendToTiff As Boolean = True, _
                         Optional DocType As scanDocType = scanAuto, _
                         Optional HRes As Integer = 150, _
                         Optional VRes As Integer = 150, _
                         Optional width As Double = 8.5, _
                         Optional height As Double = 11, _
                         Optional UseADF As Boolean = False) As Boolean
    'Windows Imaging Acquisition (WIA) Constants
Const ScannerDeviceType = 1
Const wiaIntentColor As Long = 1
Const wiaIntentGray As Long = 2
Const wiaIntentBlackWhite As Long = &H10004  '&H4 = IntentBlackWhite + &H10000 = Minimize Size   '&H20000'131072

Dim cd As Object    'WIA.CommonDialog
Dim dev As Object    'WIA.Device
Dim ip As Object    'WIA.ImageProcess
Dim Prop As Object    'WIA.Property
Dim img As Object    'WIA.ImageFile

Dim Intent As Long
Dim MorePages As Boolean

    On Error GoTo Err_ScanPage

    ScanPage = False

    'Verify scanned page can be saved
    If Len(m_sFileName) = 0 Then
        Err.Raise 5, , "Scan Aborted - No filename provided"
    ElseIf IsTiff And AppendToTiff Then
        'we're ok
    ElseIf m_bFileExists And Not OverWrite Then
        Err.Raise 58    'File already exists
    End If

    Set cd = CreateObject("WIA.CommonDialog")
    Set dev = cd.ShowSelectDevice(ScannerDeviceType)
    Set ip = CreateObject("WIA.ImageProcess")


    'Set up conversion filter
    ip.Filters.Add ip.FilterInfos("Convert").FilterID
    ip.Filters(ip.Filters.Count).Properties("FormatID").Value = FileFormat
    Select Case FileFormat
    Case wiaFormatJPEG
        ip.Filters(ip.Filters.Count).Properties("Quality").Value = 85
    Case wiaFormatTIFF
        'IP.Filters(IP.Filters.Count).Properties("Compression").Value = "CCITT4"
    End Select

    'Set intent for current document
    If DocType <> scanAuto Then m_eScanType = DocType
    If m_eScanType = scanDocument Then
        Intent = wiaIntentBlackWhite    'wiaIntentGray
    Else
        Intent = wiaIntentColor
    End If

    DoEvents
    If ShowScanningWizard Then
        Set img = cd.ShowAcquireImage(ScannerDeviceType, , , FileFormat)
    Else
        With dev.items(1)
            .Properties("Current Intent").Value = Intent
            .Properties("Horizontal Resolution").Value = HRes
            .Properties("Vertical Resolution").Value = VRes
            .Properties("Horizontal Extent").Value = HRes * width
            .Properties("Vertical Extent").Value = VRes * height
            If m_eScanType = scanDocument Then
                'Darken documents a bit so that handwriting is easier to see
                '   * Brightness is a value between -127 and +127
                '   * -45 was reached through trial and error and was tested on
                '     a CanoScan LiDE 20 flatbed scanner
                .Properties("Brightness").Value = -45
            End If

        End With
        On Error Resume Next
'        For Each Prop In dev.items(1).Properties
'            Debug.Print Prop.PropertyID, Prop.Name, Prop.Value
'        Next Prop
        'Scan the image
        If UseADF Then
            MorePages = True
            For Each Prop In dev.Properties
                Select Case Prop.PropertyID
                Case 3087 'Document Handling Select (1 = ADF)
                    MorePages = MorePages And (Prop.Value = 1)
                Case 3088 'Document Handling Status (1 = Page ready in ADF)
                    MorePages = MorePages And (Prop.Value = 1)
                End Select
            Next Prop
            If MorePages Then Set img = cd.ShowTransfer(dev.items(1), , True) ' dev.Items(1).Transfer()
        Else
            Set img = cd.ShowTransfer(dev.items(1), , True)
        End If
        If Err.Number <> 0 Then
            'User canceled the scan (most likely cause of error)
            Err.Clear
            ScanPage = False
            GoTo Exit_ScanPage
        End If
        On Error GoTo Err_ScanPage
    End If


    If img Is Nothing Then GoTo Exit_ScanPage
    'Convert to proper format
    Set img = ip.Apply(img)

    If IsTiff And AppendToTiff Then
        m_iNumPages = m_iNumPages + 1
        If m_iNumPages = 1 Then
            'ReDim Preserve throws an error if the array is currently empty
            ReDim m_sFNames(1 To 1)
        Else
            ReDim Preserve m_sFNames(1 To m_iNumPages)
        End If
        m_sFNames(m_iNumPages) = TempFileName(TempFilesPath, "tif")
        img.SaveFile m_sFNames(m_iNumPages)
        SaveToMultiTiff
        m_bFileExists = True
        ExtractPages
    Else
        If m_bFileExists And OverWrite Then Kill m_sFileName
        img.SaveFile m_sFileName
        m_iNumPages = 1
        m_bFileExists = True
    End If

    ScanPage = True

Exit_ScanPage:
    Exit Function
Err_ScanPage:
    Select Case Err.Number
    Case Else
        LogError Err.Number, Err.Description, "ScanPage", "clsScan"
    End Select
    Resume Exit_ScanPage
End Function
```

Comment: Hi, to your question of answering with the other involved functions of your class, I would like to see a copy of that if possible. Thanks, Jeroen

Comment: @mrdevis: There ends up being a lot of other dependencies.  The reason I originally offered to show those other parts was to help potential troubleshooters.  I've since solved my own problem so I'm less inclined to go to all the trouble of posting all of those other functions and dependencies.  If you have a specific question regarding scanning from vba or using wia, you'll be better off posting your own question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason this worked in the dev machine (Windows 7) and not production machines (Windows XP) did not have anything to do with the operating system.  The difference was actually in the driver version.  When I tested the scanner on the dev machine, it connected to Windows update and downloaded the most recent driver available for that scanner.  The WinXP machines were using older drivers for the same scanner.  By updating the scanner drivers on the WinXP machines to the latest version, it fixed my problem.